# Compatibility Issues with CityLearn 2.0b4, Gym 0.26.1, and Stable Baselines 3 2.0.0

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am currently working on a project involving CityLearn (version 2.0b4), Stable Baselines 3 (version 2.0.0), and Gym (version 0.26.1), and I have encountered an issue that I'm struggling to resolve.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

Operating System: Windows
Python Version: 3.10
Libraries:
CityLearn: 2.0b4
Stable Baselines 3: 2.0.0
Gym: 0.26.1
I am facing the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The error occurs when I attempt to run the code provided in the official CityLearn documentation(https://www.citylearn.net/quickstart.html). I have not modified a single line of the code, and I'm using the exact code snippet provided:

```
from stable_baselines3.sac import SAC
from citylearn.citylearn import CityLearnEnv
from citylearn.wrappers import NormalizedObservationWrapper, StableBaselines3Wrapper

dataset_name = 'baeda_3dem'
env = CityLearnEnv(dataset_name, central_agent=True, simulation_end_time_step=1000)
env = NormalizedObservationWrapper(env)
env = StableBaselines3Wrapper(env)
model = SAC('MlpPolicy', env)
model.learn(total_timesteps=env.time_steps*2)
observations = env.reset()

while not env.done:
    actions, _ = model.predict(observations, deterministic=True)
    observations, _, _, _ = env.step(actions)

kpis = env.evaluate().pivot(index='cost_function', columns='name', values='value')
kpis = kpis.dropna(how='all')
display(kpis)
```

I have tried various solutions and referred to the official documentation, but I am unable to find a compatible version combination that resolves this issue.

If anyone has experience with these libraries and can provide guidance or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm following the instructions exactly as provided in the official documentation, so I'm puzzled as to why I'm encountering this issue.

Thank you for your time and assistance!